# Do Django-nonrel and Django-SocialAuth play together nicely?

Tags: python, django-nonrel, django-socialauth

Anybody got Django-SocialAuth working with Django-nonrel?
Do they work together?

Please let me know if you have done it. Any gotchas to watch for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do, the only issue you'll run into if you are using a non-rel database is that the admin modules for Social_Auth will not work. They use joins. I was considering forking the project to see if I could make them work with non-rel, but I ran out of time.

What I've done is setup two separate databases. I'm storing my users and social_auth information in a relational database and the rest of my site content in MongoDB. Seems to be working well so far but the project is still under development.